# Android - Scroll of the content to top of the screen

Tags: android, scroll

I have an app with the structure of the image below (1) in my XML. I need you to do scroll, the app remains as in the image (2). I do not know how it works nicely CoordinatorLayout, NestedScrollView...

What changes do I need in my xml to get it? Thank you

[image]

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/color_primary_dark">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/fondo_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/black">

            <com.example.HackyViewPager
                android:id="@+id/home_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark"/>

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/home_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="15dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_footer"
            layout="@layout/home_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/color_primary_dark"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="center"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/tabpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey_dark" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you  try ScrollView? And what exactly you want to scroll?

Comment: I need RelativeLayout at top without disappear

Answer (score 0):

Do as below you will get an Rough Idea:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <com.example.HackyViewPager
            android:id="@+id/home_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/grey_dark"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll">
<!-- put your own design like Relative layout then viewpager etc --> 
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This just a Rough Idea, you can adjust it according to your design but don't copy paste this code as it won't work. As I have given this code to give a brief Idea how to use nestedScrollView and coordinatorLayout.
For More understanding you can check Material Design tutorials